# ValueError: Can only compare identically-labeled Series objects -python-pandas

Tags: python, pandas

I had 2 data frames:

```
FB7=

Date/Time   |Ticker |Gia today
0   2020-02-01  |CTF    |23.50
2   2020-02-01  |PXL    |8.40
3   2020-02-01  |DBC    |20.52
4   2020-02-01  |TCH    |32.42
5   2020-02-01  |DRC    |22.28
6   2020-02-01  |HSG    |7.80
8   2020-02-01  |KOS    |27.90
9   2020-02-01  |SBT    |18.02
11  2020-02-01  |MPC    |19.70
13  2020-02-01  |NKG    |7.38
15  2020-02-01  |HPG    |19.63

FB8=
    Date/Time   |Ticker |Gia today
1568    2020-07-01  |HPG    |19.39
1631    2020-07-01  |MPC    |20.40
1724    2020-07-01  |CTF    |21.70
1786    2020-07-01  |KOS    |28.00
1805    2020-07-01  |SBT    |18.11
1847    2020-07-01  |NKG    |7.73
1870    2020-07-01  |TCH    |33.20
1920    2020-07-01  |HSG    |7.55
1991    2020-07-01  |PXL    |8.30
2040    2020-07-01  |DBC    |20.52
2047    2020-07-01  |DRC    |23.07
```

I tried to make a list like code below:

```py
FB8[(FB8['Gia today'] >= FB7['Gia today']) & (FB8.Ticker == FB7.Ticker)]
```

and this shows me the error :

```
" ValueError Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-64-222ec9c62682> in <module>()
      8 #FB8.set_index('Ticker')
      9 FB8
---> 10 FB8[(FB8['Gia today'] >= FB7['Gia today']) & (FB8.Ticker == FB7.Ticker)]
     11 
     12 

1 frames
/usr/local/lib/python3.6/dist-packages/pandas/core/ops/__init__.py in wrapper(self, other)
    363 
    364         if isinstance(other, ABCSeries) and not self._indexed_same(other):
--> 365             raise ValueError("Can only compare identically-labeled Series objects")
    366 
    367         lvalues = extract_array(self, extract_numpy=True)

ValueError: Can only compare identically-labeled Series objects
```

What can I do to identically my labeled series object?

Comment: Please format the code using backticks

Comment: select the code or data in your text and click {} button

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try sorting the values in the column before the comparison. The code is as follows:

```
FB7.sort_values(by=["Ticker"], inplace=True, ignore_index=True)
FB8.sort_values(by=["Ticker"], inplace=True, ignore_index=True)

display(FB8[(FB8['Gia today'] >= FB7['Gia today'])])
display(FB7[(FB8['Gia today'] >= FB7['Gia today'])])
```

The output is as follows:

```
    Date/Time   Ticker  Gia today
1   2020-07-01  DBC     20.52
2   2020-07-01  DRC     23.07
5   2020-07-01  KOS     28.00
6   2020-07-01  MPC     20.40
7   2020-07-01  NKG     7.73
9   2020-07-01  SBT     18.11
10  2020-07-01  TCH     33.20

    Date/Time   Ticker  Gia today
1   2020-02-01  DBC     20.52
2   2020-02-01  DRC     22.28
5   2020-02-01  KOS     27.90
6   2020-02-01  MPC     19.70
7   2020-02-01  NKG     7.38
9   2020-02-01  SBT     18.02
10  2020-02-01  TCH     32.42
```

Also, note in this case, the dataframes must be of the same shape.

Comment: In that case, do mark it as the accepted answer :)